# Why does loop.index not work with replace?

Tags: templating

Good day!

In **Craft CMS 3**, I'm tring to configure the replacement of tags for markdown via replace, everything works except for the tag `{{ loop.index }}`

Please tell me how to properly configure to work correctly `{{ loop.index }}`?

```
{{ block.markdownContent|markdown

 |replace('<p>', '<p class="section__paragraph text">')
 |replace('<h2>', '<h2 class="section__title title">')
 |replace('<a ', '<a class="link link-color"')
 |replace('<ul>', '<ul class="attention">')
 |replace('<li>', '<li class="attention__item"><p class="attention__text">')
 |replace('</li> ', '</p></li>')
 |replace('<ol>', '<ol class="remark list">')
 |replace('<li>', '<li class="remark__item item"><p class="remark__text"><span class="remark__label">{{ loop.index }}</span>')
 |replace('</li> ', '</p></li>')|raw }}
```

Can you advise other ways of realizing this task.

Comment: `{{ loop.index }}` is usually part of Twig language. I'm not sure why/how you are going to change the syntax of the language, More important: why does your field contains Twig Syntax in the first place?

Comment: Can there be a more correct solution to the problem?

Comment: Described the problem here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25754/how-can-i-add-and-replace-classes-in-the-markdown-field

Answer (score 2):

Twig output tags won't work inside of Twig output tags.

You should be using `'<li class="remark__item item"><p class="remark__text"><span class="remark__label">'~loop.index~'</span>'`

The overall approach seems a bit heavy-handed though.

Comment: You beat me to it by 7 secs :(

Comment: I'll remember this next time you beat me :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `{{ ... }}` echo syntax within `{{ ... }}` to return a variable. Use string concatenation instead:

```
'<span class="remark__label">' ~ loop.index ~ '</span>'
```

Comment: Yes, this is how the numbering works, but it does not work, it gives out 1 1 1 1

Comment: `loop.index` not returning what you want is a different issue. Can you open a new question where you share the code including your for-loops please (and leave out all irrelevant things like replace filters)?

Comment: Described the problem here: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/25754/how-can-i-add-and-replace-classes-in-the-markdown-field